# Why Does (3) Completely Ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification, algebraic-integers

I'm working through [this notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/algnum.pdf) on Algebraic Number Theory. In section 2.6 [they claim (3) is completely ramified over the larger field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhMbQ.png):

If we know that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ is in fact, $\mathbb{Z}[\omega, \sqrt[3]{2}]$, then we can just apply Kummer-Dedekind (proven in the previous section). But it looks like they don't want to use that fact here (and I'm not sure if that's even true).

From reading the notes, I was able to see that:

1. $(1-\omega)$ is a prime ideal in the ring of integers of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, and that $(3)=(1-\omega)^2$
2. Because $N_{L/K}(1+\sqrt[3]{2})=3$ (where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$), there exists a prime $P$ in the ring of integers of $L$ such over $(1-\omega)$.
3. Because the extension $L/K$ is Galois, and $Q=(1-\omega, 1+\sqrt[3]{2})$ is invariant under Gal($L/K$), *every* prime ideal over $1-\omega$ must in fact, contain $Q$ (this follows from transitivity of the action of Gal($L/K$) on the set of primes over $(1-\omega)$.

My questions are:

4. How do we know that $Q$ is prime in the ring of integers of $L$? (remember, the notes seems to avoid wanting to characterize the ring of integers of $L$ in a concrete way, so how do we know this?) I know if we do know $Q$ is prime, then $Q$ is the *only* prime over $(1-\omega)$.
5. How do we know that $Q$ must have ramification index $3$ over $(1-\omega)$? If we know the explicit characterization of the ring of integers of $L$, then I can see how we can show the residue degree is $1$, therefore, ramification index $3$?

Thank you all

Comment: Since $L/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, the ramification index of $3$ is $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$. Since $3$ is ramified in $K$ and $L/K$ is Galois, the ramification index is divisible by $2$. Since $3$ ramifies completely in ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, the ramification index is $\ge 3$. Thus $e = 6$. Since $L$ has class number $1$ you can also search for an element with norm $3$ and compute its sixth power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do *not* need to know the ring of integers of a number field $K$ in order to show a prime $p$ is totally ramified in $K$: $p$ is totally ramified in $K$ if and only if there is some $\alpha \in \mathcal O_K$ such that (i) $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ and (ii) the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q$ is Eisenstein at $p$. This is proved as Theorems 3.1 and 3.2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/totram.pdf).

**Example**. Let $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a nontrivial cube root of unity.  In $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\sqrt[3]{2}+1$ is a root of $(x-1)^3 - 2 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 3$, which is Eisenstein at $3$, so $3$ is totally ramified in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, so $3\mathcal O_K = \mathfrak p^3$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak p$.

Let $F = \mathbf Q(\omega)$. Since $F = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3})$, 3 is totally ramified in $F$ since $(3) = (\sqrt{-3})^2$ (or $\sqrt{-3}$ is a root of $x^2 + 3$, which is Eisenstein at $3$, but such reasoning is more technical than it has to be).

Let $L = \mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$.
Since $3\mathcal O_K$ is a cube and $3\mathcal O_F$ is a square, $3\mathcal O_L$ is a $6$th power, so each prime ideal dividing $3\mathcal O_L$ has multiplicity divisible by $6$. Then the formula $\sum e_if_i = n = 6$ implies $3$ is totally ramified in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$.

**Remark**. The ring $\mathcal O_L$ is *bigger* than $\mathbf Z[\sqrt[3]{2},\omega]$. See Theorem 9 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/Qw2.pdf).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I guess I also wanted to know why the specific ideal given is also a prime ideal, etc. but I guess it doesn't quite matter now. I see that the ramification index is divisible by 2 and 3, therefore, is 6.

Answer (score 3):

The subtlety is that $\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2^{1/3}+1}$ is an algebraic integer whose [minimal polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimal+polynomial+%28-3%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%282%5E%281%2F3%29%2B1%29) is of degree $6$ and Eisenstein at $3$.

Showing that every prime numbers factorize in products of prime ideals we get that $$O_K = \Bbb{Z}[\omega,2^{1/3},\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2^{1/3}+1}]$$

(if $p\ge 5$ then $p$ is unramified in $\Bbb{Z}[\omega,2^{1/3}]$ so it factorizes in prime ideals, then $(2)=(2^{1/3})^3$ and $(3)=(3,\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2^{1/3}+1})^6$)